# An efficient estimator can be biased?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, efficiency

Can someone explain to me whether an efficient estimator can be biased? What I've read so far seems to be always about efficiency being a property being alluded to unbiased estimators but I was thinking that a biased estimator with smaller variance can thus be efficient. I am unsure if my main question has a single definitive answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about what it means for an efficient estimator to be biased?

Comment: Related [Biased and Efficient estimators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152311/biased-and-efficient-estimators)